# Extract values from .txt file to .xlsx

Tags: python, csv, xlsx, txt

I need to extract specific values ​​from a text file with content like

> spam: 1; eggs: (2, 3, 4)
> spam: 5; eggs: (6, 7, 8)

And I need to put them into separate columns in an excel file. I don't know if I should use re for this, is there perhaps an easier way of doing it?

---

Updated: I've started with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

f_path = "C:/path"

f_input = os.path.join(f_path, 'log.txt')
f_output = os.path.join(f_path, 'log.csv')

df = pd.read_csv(f_input, sep='\t')
df.to_csv(f_output, index=False)
```

Now I have this output in a .csv file, however, I would like it to look like this:

Sheet1:

| spam |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 5 |

Sheet2:

| eggs |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |

How can I attain such a result?

Answer (score 0):

why re? you can simply read lines from text file and write them to a csv using this script below

```py
def extract_values_from_text_file(text_file_path, csv_file_path):
    with open(text_file_path, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        with open(csv_file_path, "w") as f:
            for line in lines:
                line = line.replace(":", ",")
                f.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you! I've managed to extract the lines from the .txt file using the code above. However, now I want to convert these lines into Excel data properly.

Comment: open excel and do import from csv and import this file